# Redis: invalid DB index

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I recently launched a redis database through AWS and wanted to do a few tests with some initial dummy code. When running the code on an EC2 instance within the same VPC, I'm hitting an error: `redis.exceptions.ResponseError: invalid DB index`.

Here is the code:

```
import redis
import pickle
import zlib
EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 600
r = redis.Redis(host='dse-inventory-orders.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com',
                port=6379, db='dse-inventory-orders')
r.set('foo', 'bar')
r.get('foo')

logger.info(f"r.get('foo'): {r.get('foo')}")
```

Here is the error message. Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/scripts/redis_test.py", line 25, in <module>
r.set('foo', 'bar')
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1801, in set
return self.execute_command('SET', *pieces)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 898, in execute_command
conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1192, in get_connection
connection.connect()
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 567, in connect
self.on_connect()
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 664, in on_connect
if nativestr(self.read_response()) != 'OK':
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 756, in read_response
raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: invalid DB index
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(39): Subprocess for 'conda run ['/bin/bash', '/usr/local/bin/fetch_and_run.sh', 'pythonRunnerCplex.sh', 's3://srdata-lab/ipredict_dev/dynamic_scheduling_engine/scripts/redis_test.py', 'redis_test.py']' command failed. Stderr was:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/scripts/redis_test.py", line 25, in <module>
r.set('foo', 'bar')
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1801, in set
return self.execute_command('SET', *pieces)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 898, in execute_command
conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1192, in get_connection
connection.connect()
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 567, in connect
self.on_connect()
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 664, in on_connect
if nativestr(self.read_response()) != 'OK':
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 756, in read_response
raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: invalid DB index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While establishing your connection;

```
redis.Redis(host='dse-inventory-orders.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com',
                port=6379, db='dse-inventory-orders')
```

you used `db` as `dse-inventory-orders`(string), but according to the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/select);

> Select the Redis logical database having the specified **zero-based numeric index**. New connections always use the database 0.

So replace it with `0`, it will work.